# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, real-time

Tengo una app que trae datos de RealTime de firebase pero me sale un error que no me da con mas datos, hago el llamado a los datos con el primer databasereference y obtengo esos datos para agregarlos a una lista esos datos funcionan bien pero en el segundo databasereference que se encuentra dentro de onDataChange del primer databasereference me da el siguiente error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.smbr_v21.model.urls.UrlUser
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:423)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:214)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:212)
    at com.example.smbr_v21.view.activitys.NoticesActivity$6$1.onDataChange(NoticesActivity.java:288)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6144)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Pero no comprendo porque me da ese error, ya revise las variables si puede ser que no coinciden pero todas estan bien, este es mi codigo que trae los datos de RealTime:

```
emailNode = firebaseUser.getEmail().replace(".", "-");
    emailNodeNew = emailNode.replace("@", "_");
    Log.i(Constants.TAG_NOTICES_ACTIVITY, "user >> " + firebaseUser.getEmail() +
            "\nuserMod >> " + emailNodeNew);

    dialog.setMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_DIALOG);
    dialog.show();

    databaseReference.child(Constants.DATES_NODE_POST)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        for(DataSnapshot dsd : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            DatesNotices datesNotices = dsd.getValue(DatesNotices.class);

                            datesGet.add(datesNotices.getNickname());
                            datesGet.add(datesNotices.getTitle());
                            datesGet.add(datesNotices.getDate());
                            datesGet.add(datesNotices.getText());

                            databaseReference.child(Constants.DATES_NODE)
                                    .child(Constants.DATES_NODE_URLS)
                                    .child(emailNodeNew)
                                    .child("urlUser")
                                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                                linearNoPosts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                Log.i(Constants.TAG_NOTICES_ACTIVITY, "Exist");
                                                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                                    UrlUser urlUser = ds.getValue(UrlUser.class); //Línea del error
                                                    urlPerfil = urlUser.getUrlUserPerfil();
                                                    Log.w(Constants.TAG_NOTICES_ACTIVITY, urlUser.getUrlUserPerfil());

                                                    addObjects(datesGet, urlPerfil);
                                                }
                                            } else{
                                                Log.i(Constants.TAG_NOTICES_ACTIVITY, "No-Exist");
                                                deleteNoticesRefresh();
                                                linearNoPosts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            }

                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                            Log.w(Constants.TAG_NOTICES_ACTIVITY, "Error al traer los datos:\n" +
                                                    databaseError);
                                            Toast.makeText(NoticesActivity.this,
                                                    "Hubo un error al cargar las publicaciones",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    } else{
                        Log.i(Constants.TAG_NOTICES_ACTIVITY, "No-Exist");
                        deleteNoticesRefresh();
                        linearNoPosts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.w(Constants.TAG_NOTICES_ACTIVITY, "Error al traer los datos:\n" +
                            databaseError);
                    Toast.makeText(NoticesActivity.this,
                            "Hubo un error al cargar las publicaciones",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Este es mi modelo UrlUser.class:

```
public class UrlUser {

    private String urlUserPerfil;

    public UrlUser() {
    }

    public UrlUser(String urlUserPerfil) {
        this.urlUserPerfil = urlUserPerfil;
    }

    public String getUrlUserPerfil() {
        return urlUserPerfil;
    }

    public void setUrlUserPerfil(String urlUserPerfil) {
        this.urlUserPerfil = urlUserPerfil;
    }
}
```

he revisado firebase pero tampoco veo ningun error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como dice el error, no puede convertir un String a otro objeto, aunque este contenga un parametro String.

Así es como falla

```
    UrlUser urlUser = ds.getValue(UrlUser.class);
```

Cámbialo así

```
UrlUser urlUser = new UrlUser(ds.getValue(String.class))
```

Ya que tienes un constructor UrlUser que acepta un String, úsalo.

---

No se exactamente como funciona el `DataSnapshot`, pero si puedes obtener el String, no te complicaras con parses entre objetos.